# Logical meaning to morphisms between prehilbertian spaces

Tags: logic, hilbert-spaces

I was wondering how one can give a logical meaning to morphisms between prehilbertian spaces. If I was to consider such a morphism $f$ as a logical morphism between two $L$-structures, I should have in my language $L$ a binary function symbol $<.,.>$ corresponding to the scalar product, because $<f(x),f(y)>=<x,y>$. Though the interpretation of a binary function symbol is always a function from $E \times E$ to $E$ (where $E$ is the base set of my $L$-structure), and not a function from $E \times E$ to $\mathbb{C}$ as in the case of a scalar product. Though it feels so much like a logical morphism...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to formalise vector space theory is to use a two-sorted language with a sort (what you call a "base") for vectors and another sort for scalars. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)#Many-sorted_structures.